# Modeling of a conical base tank

Tags: calculus, volume

Consider the following diagram of a empty tank being filled with a liquid

[image]

Considering constant and equal denstity, it's total mass balance is

$$\frac{dV_1}{dt}=q_e-q_s$$

But I don't know how to model $V(h)$

I do know that below $h_0$

$$V=\frac{h \pi r^2}{3}$$

where

$$r(h)=\frac{R_t}{h_0} h$$

And that above $h_0$

$$V=h \pi R_t^2 + \frac{h \pi r^2}{3}$$

But how do I consider bot volumes in a single expresion of $V(h)$ considering their respective conditions of $h \le h_o$ and $h>h_0$ respectively?

Comment: If the tank is indeed being drained faster than the volume gets replaced, you can use [step functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) to address this behavior.